# HP ProLiant DL380 G7 servers will not POST

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hardware

We have just received 2 HP DL380 G7's from our DR site. They have been running fine at the site for some time but we have tried to power them up in our DC and they will not post. We get a very brief flash of the post screen and then the systems power cycle. Both systems behave in the same way. Has anyone come across this issue before? There are no beep codes. We have tried removing the battery as well as the hard disks but it appears to be an issue that occurs prior to the system posting.

Comment: To clarify the above comment, you need to be looking for the IML log on the ILO page - iLO should be set to DHCP by default (Unless you've configured it previously) so you can use your DHCP server to determine the IP.

Comment: I will go have a look. I believe that the DR vendor had acess to the ILO but hopefully it was DHCP. I will come back shortly thanks.

Comment: Ok so there is no address allocated to the ILO's. Would removing the bios battery reset the ILO config or does it have it's own battery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your KVM... Try with different keyboard/monitor or run headless. Don't repeat the mistakes made [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen).

See: [HP ProLiant DL360 G7 hangs at "Power and Thermal Calibration" screen](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen)

---

Edit: It would be important to get into the ILO to see server messages. The ILO's settings are persistent, so removing the battery won't help you. Even if your issue is not KVM-related, the rest of the flowchart above should help you isolate the issue.

If you have physical access to the server, you can try this sequence:

- Remove the power supply units and swap them.

Test to see if the system will boot...

If that doesn't work:

- Remove all power supplies from the chassis
- Locate the *System Maintenance Switch* on the motherboard - It's a set of 10 DIP switches.
- Turn switch #6 switch on.
- Insert all power supply units.
- Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
- Power the server off.
- Remove all power supplies.
- Return DIP switch #6 to off (original) position.
- Reinsert the power supplies.
- Power the server on.

Test to see if the system will boot...

If that doesn't work:

- Remove all power supplies from the chassis
- Turn DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 switch on.
- Insert all power supply units.
- Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
- Power the server off.
- Remove all power supplies.
- Return DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 to off (original) position.
- Reinsert the power supplies.
- Power the server on.

Test to see if the system will boot...

---

[image: oops]

Comment: thanks for that, we have used our KVM and 2 standalone monitors directly connected as part of our initial testing.

Comment: @user3045672 See my edit above for the troubleshooting sequence to use in this situation.

Comment: Thanks ewwhite! I followed your flow chart and then tried the first dip switch setting and all is now good!

Comment: @user3045672 Magic!!! (it's actually clearing the NVRAM)

Comment: Awesome, I didn't even check, just followed your tips :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a high enough ranking to post comments yet, so I'm posting this as a new answer, but it's really an addition to the existing thorough answer.

Before replacing power supplies, we tried the following and it worked:

1. power down
2. unplug power cable
3. wait 2+ minutes
4. plug in power cable
5. power up

We got POST at that point.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar issue with correcting the memory modules sitting in the right slots
It turned out that 2 out of 10 modules had the wrong place - preventing the server to come across the 2 blue items on the screen