# HP Proliant Gen8 boot failure after bios upgrade and processor upgrade

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, bios, firmware

We have a HP Proliant DL360P with one Intel Xeon e5-2650, and we was in need to use two Xeon e5-2670 V2, this server by default this G8 did not recognizes the v2 processor, so we found [this procedure](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/mostViewedDisplay?sp4ts.oid=5177949&javax.portlet.tpst=efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01&javax.portlet.prp_efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Dmmr_kc-0110152-6%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) so we did the BIOS Firmware update to most recently (2014) and after we did the processor self-upgrade procedure as described on the link.

Changed the processor and it worked, and after a power-off / power-on it did not booted, in the SID panel it said that the processor was the fault, so we changed back the processor to the e5-2650, and it keept saying that the processor was the fault.

We removed the batery to clear the BIOS and after it botted but appeared a very mess strange characters in the display.

I'm now downloading the Firmware maintenance v10.1 from FTP of HP to make the procedure [described here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02785606-1%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) but I want to check with you if with your knowledged if you now something about it

Comment: What other errors are you receiving? Have you rebooted several times? How far does the server get during POST?

Answer (score 5):

Risky upgrade...

Remove power from the server. Unplug the cables. Let the machine sit for a few minutes. Plug the cables back in and power on.

If this doesn't work, you'll want to reset NVRAM.

Take a look at the [**HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 Server Maintenance and Service Guide**](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03242811-8.pdf)

You have to clear the CPU errors... Try the sequence [detailed here](https://serverfault.com/questions/565736/hp-proliant-dl385-g6-fan-solution-not-sufficient-error/565756#565756).

> If you have physical access to the server, you can try this sequence:
>
> - Remove the power supply units and swap them.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...
>
> If that doesn't work:
>
> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Locate the *System Maintenance Switch* on the motherboard - It's a set of 10 DIP switches.
> - Turn switch #6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switch #6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...
>
> If that doesn't work:
>
> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Turn DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunally none of what you said worked, I'm uploading a video to youtube that show the error and I'm doing this procedure http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02785606-1%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Comment: I'd call HP support.

Comment: I've aborted the procedure and called HP Support, they said the they will change the motherboard, I'm still uploading the video to you take a look of what is happening, it's so strange.

Answer (score 3):

There's a special firmware update needed to allow the use of E5-2600V2 CPUs in systems originally equipped with V1 CPUs.

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03911173&lang=en-us&cc=us

Comment: Was after this procedure that occurred the error.

Answer (score -1):

in ilo you should switch 
ROM too your backup ROM...   then upgrading your rom should replace the other ROM with the one u u upgraded from