# HP Proliant DL360 G7 All DIMM indicator lights amber

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

I am currently doing a RAM upgrade on an HP proliant DL360 G7 server.  After installing the new RAM (18x 8GB KTH-PL316E/8G) the LED indicator lights for every single DIMM turned amber and the health check light turned red. I tried putting some older RAM back into the server to see if the new RAM was the problem, but the server still had every single DIMM amber, even though every DIMM was not populated. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the BIOS to see why they were showing amber?

Comment: iLO3 is configured. The new RAM I am trying to use is kingston, but the old RAM that I am testing it with now is Samsung. I'm not sure what the old RAM configuration was, as when I started working on the box this morning the old RAM configuration had already been removed

Comment: In my case I was restarting my HP Proliant Dl385 g7 when it started beeping and all the dimm leds were in amber. I opened the top lid dusted off the machine removed the rams cleaned them and placed them back. And the machine was up and running.

Comment: As we make VERY clear when you sign up to this site it is a question and answer site, NOT a forum - please read our help pages and observe how the site works before posting again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hmm, that's Kingston RAM. Are you *absolutely* sure it is compatible? (*I advocate using HP RAM in HP servers*)

What was the old RAM configuration?

I'd suggest going back to the old configuration...

To start, please remove power (and power cables) from the system for a few minutes. Plug them back in and try again. Also, is your ILO3 configured? You can use that to review the server's IML log and see *why* your RAM is giving you an error or any other relevant POST messages.

For the new RAM, please ensure it is seated properly. The DL360 G7 has 18 DIMM slots, so you're filling it up. Weird things happen when you approach the limits of a platform like this. So the best case is to start small and popular one DIMM per CPU and build up from there.

**EDIT:**

You're using unbuffered RAM. That server will only support 96GB of unbuffered memory... so 12 modules.

Please use the right RAM for the server (500662-B21) if you intend to max the server out.

Comment: I think youre right about the 8GB RAM not being compatible with the server. However, I've replaced the 18 8GB with only 12 2GB and I am still getting amber light indicators even for the DIMMS that do not have any RAM in them

Comment: Good spot on the unbuffered - I've never heard of anyone ever using that so it didn't leap out at me, well done

Comment: @ewwhite So would using that RAM cause some issue with the server that would cause it to keep showing these error lights? Because even now with supported RAM I am getting amber lights on every single dimm, even those that are not populated

Comment: Examine the IML log in the ILO3 interface.

Comment: The only error the log is showing is "Maintenance note: Memory Configuration Error: System boot halted." So definitely related to memory, but not a whole lot of useful information there.

Comment: Clear the error, put known-good RAM in and try again.

Comment: So I cleared the error log, put in a small amount of known good RAM (enough to populate one channel on each processor with 3 2GB sticks) and restarted the machine, and yet it still continues to show every single DIMM as an amber light

Comment: @Allfer2 Then you need to run through the sequence of steps [detailed here](http://serverfault.com/questions/609338/hp-proliant-g8-boot-failure-after-bios-upgrade-and-processor-upgrade/609344#609344). If that doesn't work, call HP.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the issue here - if you look on the compatibility tab of [THIS](http://www.uk.insight.com/en-gb/productinfo/computer-memory/0001399066) link you'll see it's not a supported configuration. Presumably because it's 12800 memory rather than the 1066 or 1333 memory HP sell but it could be another factor - either way next time be more careful selecting products, if in doubt always buy from the vendor for this exact reason.

Comment: I understand that that is the issue with the new RAM, but why is the server still showing those health errors even after the RAM was switched out?

Comment: @Allfer2 Did you remove the power from the machine and let it sit?

Comment: @ewwhite Let it sit for about 5 minutes with power unplugged. Plugged it back in and powered it up and all dimms still show up amber