# HP DL380 Gen8 doesn't turn on

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

We have a HP DL380 Gen8 in one of our data center and it is connected to a UPS, I checked the ILO and know that due to unstable electric powe,r the server has been shutdown with the following error:

"System has enabled power protection and disabled power supplies".

I did a little searching and I tried the following attempts:

1. Replacing power supplies.
2. Using another power supply.
3. Changing the power cords.
4. [Resetting the NVRAM](https://serverfault.com/questions/609338/hp-proliant-gen8-boot-failure-after-bios-upgrade-and-processor-upgrade).
5. Updating Firmware.
6. Updating CPLD.

Basically I tired everything I could think of.
The problem is when I turn on the server after waiting for few minutes the server doesn't turn on and I get a flashing Red/Oragnish light.

Can anyone help me out with this please.
Does this mean the motherboard has burn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, Gen8 ProLiant servers are all still under factory warranty right now. Your best option at this point is to call HP support. I haven't seen this issue on any of my servers, but [there's documentation](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Problems-with-Proliant-DL560-Gen-8/td-p/6095739#.VB7vm0vDvSw) of others with this issue.

Are you sure you upgraded firmware to the newest revision? *How* did you run the firmware update? Does the system [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test)? [This advisory](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/advisoriesDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c04042380-1%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.tpst=efb5c0793523e51970c8fa22b053ce01&sp4ts.oid=5177957&ac.admitted=1411313677762.876444892.492883150) covers the issue you speak of, but you say you've updated.

Use HP's support here. You've already taken more troubleshooting steps than should be necessary.